# Windows batch file: rename files (possibly in multiple folders) based on input file (of target filenames)

Tags: windows, batch, rename

I am a Batch-newbie...

This "tool" is to automate the slimming down of Windows (XP) by disabling certain system driver, DLL and EXE files.  Instead of outright deletion, I wish to rename-in-place, thus "removing" them from the OS, but not losing sight of where they belong (should any need to be "restored").  Renaming is accomplished by appending a new suffix to the existing filename (eg: "wdmaud.drv.group_1")  The renaming suffix should be another input variable.

The target-list is approx. 1100 files long (divided into various groups/phases), so manual renaming is out of the question.  Each group will be processed in a separate run of the batch file, varying the target-list input file for each execution.

Target-list is plain text file, one filename per line (no other data in the files).  Number of entries per group varies.  Target list will look like this:

```
    -- example start --
    netapi.dll
    netcfgx.dll 
    netdde.exe 
    netevent.dll 
    nic1394.sys
    -- example end --
```

Filenames may be in UPPER, lower, or MiXeD case.  The files may be present in more than one folder in the C:\Windows hierarchy - or may not be present at all.  If a file is not found anywhere in the system, it's name should be written to a text file, one-entry-per-line.

The specific folders of interest are:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\
    C:\WINDOWS\system\
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllcache
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers
```

...but may change as development proceeds.

Based on a reply at stackoverflow.com, I've got started thus:

```
    @echo off

    set suffix=GROUP_1
    set targetlist=GROUP_1.txt
    set dirlist=folders.txt

    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%targetlist%) do (
      for /f "tokens=*" %%d in (%dirlist%) do (
        if exist "%%d\%%f" ren "%%d\%%f.%%suffix"
           echo %%f found in %%d >> foundlist.txt
      )
    )
```

==============================================================================

```
    :: -----------------------------------------------------------------::
    :: Batch Process to Rename-In-Place System Files from an Input List ::
    :: -----------------------------------------------------------------::

    @echo off
    :: >> clear files from previous run <<
    if exist RENAMED_files.txt  DEL RENAMED_files.txt
    if exist NOTFound_files.txt DEL NOTFound_files.txt

    ::  >> file rename-suffix reflects step name <<
    set suffix=Steppe_01

    ::  >> target file list to rename <<
    set targetlist=Steppe_01_files.txt

    ::  >> list of folders to search  <<
    set dirlist=folders.txt

    ::  >> PROCESS <<

    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%targetlist%) do (
      echo. >> NOTFound_files.txt
      for /f "tokens=*" %%d in (%dirlist%) do (
        if NOT exist "%%d\%%f"          echo %%f  not in %%d >> NOTFound_files.txt
        if exist     "%%d\%%f"          REN "%%d\%%f" "%%f.%suffix%"
        if exist     "%%d\%%f.%suffix%" echo renamed  %%f  in %%d >> RENAMED_files.txt
      )
    )

    ::  >> end of process <<
```

Comment: Windows File Protection is about to hit you over the head with a large hammer.  Don't say later that you weren't warned.

Comment: What is the question?